# How do i set response_header_timeout in Thanos Query Frontend Manifest?

Tags: syntax, yaml, response-headers, observability, thanos

1. 

I want to increase the response_header_timeout in thanos query-frontend deployment manifest as my queries are timing out, but can't find the correct syntax format expected.

Current Syntax I am following:

```yaml
        - -|
          --query-frontend.downstream-tripper-config="config":
          "response_header_timeout": "5m"
```

Other Syntax I have tried:

```
--query-frontend.downstream-tripper-config.response_header_timeout="5m"
```

But invalid.

Documentation Reference Link:
[Query-Frontend Flags](https://thanos.io/tip/components/query-frontend.md/#recommended-downstream-tripper-configuration)

Example Manifest File:
[Example Manifest File](https://github.com/thanos-io/kube-thanos/blob/main/examples/all/manifests/thanos-query-frontend-deployment.yaml)

Example shown in docs:
[How to use config flags?](https://thanos.io/tip/thanos/tracing.md/#how-to-use-config-flags)

2.
Also there is a type mentioned in the example manifest file like:
`type: "memcached"`
What flag do I need to write in for query-frontend?

After editing the file, the deployment tried to use the edited file to create the pods but it sent the pod in CrashBackLoopOff state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: it will work in this format.

```
    - |-
      --query-frontend.downstream-tripper-config=
      "response_header_timeout": "5m"
```

I had the same issue and based on the error log, it doesn't expect to receive the params nested under `"config":` and fails to parse the yaml.

Log example: (Line 1: field config not found)
`level=error ts=2023-07-27T11:21:06.840839711Z caller=main.go:135 err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: field config not found in type queryfrontend.DownstreamTripperConfig\nparsing downstream tripper`

I guess that`"config":` is unnecessary here because DownstreamTripperConfig is already a `type`, as there are no different types so you just list all parameters there as they are.

I found it here: https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos/blob/a817dbf586244bb7cbaa182bf830ad30b7e03944/pkg/queryfrontend/config.go#L181
It expects to read params directly from the provided yaml, e.g., `yaml:"idle_conn_timeout"`

Comparing to CacheProviderConfig config, e.g. memcached, where it expects a different yaml format with `"config"` and `"type"`
https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos/blob/a817dbf586244bb7cbaa182bf830ad30b7e03944/pkg/queryfrontend/config.go#L84

Hope it helps :)